# SSRS 2008 R2: How to generate a expression based Date column while exporting Excel Report?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

**SSRS 2008 R2:** I have created a report(.rdl) using Shared datasource. I am following the tabular approach to generate the report. I need an extra column in my report which uses the excel formula to calculate the date based on two existing columns.

The formula which I am using for the new column **MMM/YYYY** is **=DATE(A2, B2, 1)**

[image: Expected Report]

I have tried creating the expression for the new column, but it is not purely giving me the desired output.

Comment: Can you achieve  this output by changing the query of the data source?

Comment: Yes, I am querying from the datasource for now. But here we require the dynamic column whose value can be changed by applying the formula to it. I am trying to create the expression based column but not able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: You can try  cDate() function to convert string to datetimeobject, I hope it helps    =Format(CDate(Fields!A.Value), "MMMM yyyy")

Comment: It is not working, I guess it will work for the column that already has date value as a string. But here I have Month and Year in two columns. How can I use cDate() function here to append these two column values and then convert it into datetime.

Comment: Before using cDate function can please you try to concat month and year? CDate(Fields!A.Value& "-"Fields!B.Value& "-"Fields!C.Value)

Comment: @Pelin Yes, I have tried this way and managed to get the desired output. **=Format(CDate(Fields!Year_Name.Value & "-" & Fields!Month_Of_Year.Value & "-" & "1"), "dd-MM-yyyy")**. Thanks for your time and quick response.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent expression in SSRS to =DATE(A2,B2,1) would be

`=DateSerial(Fields!Year.Value,Fields!Month.Value,1)`

Then format the relevant textbox using the same format code you would use in excel.